# Iptables exception for specific port

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn, openvpn

I'm new to iptables but configured a simple natting today on my raspian:

```
# Always accept loopback traffic
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun0 -j REJECT

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

So as you can see I also use openvpn and redirect the traffic to the tunnel interface.
I'd like to create an exception for example for the port range 900 to 999 and source 192.168.1.5 to be excluded and sent directly to interface eth1 and avoid the vpn encryption.

How can I create such a rule?

Thanks a lot for your input.

EDIT: I tried something like

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 900:999 --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

But it doesn't seem to have the expected effect...

Answer (score 2):

You would need policy routing to set up routing tables for each specific traffic.  I've found a concise and good example in [Linux Advanced Routing Mini HOWTO](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html).

Put the following line in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
1 DIRECT
```

Then you can do like:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 900:999 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip route add default via <gateway address> dev eth1 table DIRECT
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table DIRECT
ip rule add from 192.168.1.5/32 table DIRECT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this out when I get back from work and provide some feedback.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this routing. I can't get any connection from 192.168.1.5 to the outside anymore. I guess I need to make iptables for eth1 now to allow incoming/outgoing connections for this interface but I haven't figured this out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue with your help.
Had to add additional rules for incoming and outcoming over eth1 and alter the PREROUTING condition to only match the ip 192.168.1.5 instead of adding a rule.
The routing approach with
    ip rule add from 192.168.1.5/32 table DIRECT
caused all traffic from 192.168.1.5 to go over eth1 instead of only port 900-999.
The final configuration looks like this:

```
# Always accept loopback traffic
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun0 -j REJECT

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Port exceptions
# Added -s for source address 192.168.1.5 here
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.5 -p tcp --dport 900:999 -j MARK --set-mark 1

ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 table DIRECT
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table DIRECT
```

Thanks again for your help.